# Getting the shortest sequence to reach a number (+,-,*,/)

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a task:
The program gets a single number as input and the output would be the count of steps needed to get to that number from 0.
Rules:

- the order of execution is from left to right, so +,-,* and / are all
  equal.
- if the number gets under negative, 10 000 is added  (you can get number 9996 by doing only 0 - 4)
- if the partresult is more than 10000, the program only remembers last 4 digits
- division can be only made if the result would be integral ( 5 / 4 is not possible)
- you can only use number 4

Example input:

```
42
```

Example output:

```
9
```

Shortest solution is:

```
 4 + 4 + 4 * 4 - 4 * 4 - 4 - 4 / 4
```

I don't really need the whole solution, so if you could just push me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it your assignment?

Comment: Kind of, thats why I'm not asking for a full solution, just a direction. I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Raxume Thanks for accepting my answer :) SO advice to let 24-48 Hours pass before accepting an answer, this is to encourage other people to answer too and then choose the most fitting answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start thinking from the "naive" solution, and try improve the ideas.

### MOST NAIVE

1. build a tree with "4" as root, and each node branch into 4 (for each operation)
2. build the tree, level by level, until you find the number you wish to get.

*e.g.*
Lv1: 4
Lv2: 4+4=8, 4-4=0, 4*4=16, 4/4=1
Lv3: 8+4, 8-4, 8*4, 8/4,, 0+4, 0-4, 0*4, 0/4 ...
...

of-course: this has exponential complexity which is pretty bad.

### Solution enhancement

we can see that many of the branches are "DEAD-ENDS" which can be cut.
and moreover, some (many) numbers will repeat themselves, and their branch can be 'reused'

In other words:
when creating a Node for number X, save the new Node in a Hash under X,
and when eventually you encounter X, instead of creating a new Node, direct it to the already created one.
*Note*: this branch is discontinued for it is looping through, already known values.

I don't have the time to model the complexity of this solution, but it should be feasible solution for most numbers.

### Furthermore

If we look closely, we can easily see that this tree won't change per function call, for either number... only grow and expand,
therefore, after the first few runs, we are more likely to find the requested number in our "hash" @ ~O(1),
and if it isn't there, we are closer to it then if we didn't.

### TOTALLY Different (yet incomplete) Approach

this thought isn't complete, but i think it is worth to mention for you to expand on.
we might be able to get away with a greedy approach:

- multiply by 4 as long as `x*4 < N`
- Add 4 as long as `x+4<N`
- 4/4 = 1   =>   Add 3,2,1 accordingly.

*Note:* you need to think about the Order issue here, and about the fact that numbers can be wrapped around 10,000.

but it is a start.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/BPriVjrY) this is the program i've created, it works, but fails at some inputs(for example 9501, 8323). what do you think about it? thanks for your time.

Comment: didn't read the program, but what fails? it doesn't find the value? crash? smth else?

Comment: the value is just wrong - no crashes, no infinite loops.

Comment: why wrong? found a shorter way? did you try printing the "trace" and it was calculated wrong?

Comment: That's the issue, I have no idea why, there's the trace for 8323 [link](http://pastebin.com/KUz11i11)

Comment: there is a chance that there isn't a solution... 
Here is a JS implementation http://jsbin.com/jeqanipuri/1/edit?html,js,output it isn't working fast enough, and it is far from being optimal...
and if you raise the `itteration_max` expect for several minutes operation.

Comment: when i said trace, i meant you to print some data about the tree creation.
and finally the path that was found.
if you get to wiered values, you might want to use the Debugger.

Comment: after a bit of rechecking, there might be a situation for Numbers you just cant reach whithin the given constraints.

Comment: Okay, identified the issue: (Value - 4) % 10000, when value=3 won't result in 9999 but in -1, that was the whole problem it seems, thanks for your time.